# Implementing a drop down form in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I basically want to have a form that can toggle between a simple and a detailed mode.

Whats the best way to go about implementing this in Swing?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a BorderLayout. Put the detail panel in the south and make it invisible. Then when you click the "Details" button you set the panel visible and pack() the frame. Or if you don't want the frame to change size then you would need to revalidate() and repaint() the parent container.